# Google Script get a text from a cell(Spredsheet special characters like ç, à,é,è ) and search for it in a Google Doc document

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I did a script (container-bound script) in my Spreadsheet in which I have 4 columns: (1) text before, (2) text after, (3) text to insert between, and (4) a URL of a Google Doc with the text in which I want to replace with the right value (between).

My method replace is not working when I have a french text (with characters like ç , à, è ) but with an english text it works fine  How to solve this? Thank you very much for your help  any idea is welcomed this is what I've done so far https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dOVNMrzEHvi3-vU3nbftK3Xoinxscrkn and my code :

```js
/** It works for a text without accents :) but not for a french text :(   **/
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update the Google Doc") ;
  
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var COLUMN_URL = 3 ;
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues(); 
  
  var start = 1;
  var URL = data[start][COLUMN_URL];
  Logger.log(' URL ' + URL);
  var body = DocumentApp.openByUrl(URL).getBody();
  
  
  var text_before = sheet.getRange(start + 1,1).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_before is "  + text_before );
  
  var text_after = sheet.getRange(start + 1,2).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_after is " +  text_after );
  
  var text_between = sheet.getRange(start + 1,3).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_between is " +  text_between );
  
  /** replace in the body of the Google Doc  **/
  
  // important to do this for the apostrophe and the " symbols that are different put the symbol in the cell
  body.replaceText("\\Q’\\E","'");
  // works 
  body.replaceText("\\Q”\\E",'"') 
  // ???? replace all unsupported characters from sheet means in my cell 
 
  /** symbols to test which works >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ok for the McDonald*?()\.,;%#(){!s . how about the "  ***/
  body.replaceText( "\\Q" + text_before + "\\E" +  ".*?"  + "\\Q" + text_after + "\\E", text_before + text_between + text_after ); 
  
  /** another example   **/
  var start_bis = 2;
  var text_before_bis = sheet.getRange(start_bis + 1,1).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_before is "  + text_before_bis );
  
  var text_after_bis = sheet.getRange(start_bis + 1,2).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_after is " +  text_after_bis );
  
  var text_between_bis = sheet.getRange(start_bis + 1,3).getDisplayValue().replace(/[”|-’]/g,".");
  Logger.log("text_between is " +  text_between_bis );
  
  /** replace in the body of the Google Doc  **/
  body.replaceText( "\\Q" + text_before_bis + "\\E" +  ".*?"  + "\\Q" + text_after_bis + "\\E", text_before_bis + text_between_bis + text_after_bis ); 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use replace. Just `\\Q...\\E` will work fine in this case. After replacing, `.` is considered a literal text due to (QE). Hence, it wasn't working.
Try

```
/** It works for a text without accents :) but not for a french text :(   **/
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update the Google Doc") ;

  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var COLUMN_URL = 3 ;
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues(); 

  var start = 1;
  var URL = data[start][COLUMN_URL];
  Logger.log(' URL ' + URL);
  var body = DocumentApp.openByUrl(URL).getBody();


  var text_before = sheet.getRange(start + 1,1).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("text_before is "  + text_before );

  var text_after = sheet.getRange(start + 1,2).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("text_after is " +  text_after );

  var text_between = sheet.getRange(start + 1,3).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("text_between is " +  text_between );

  /** replace in the body of the Google Doc  **/

  // important to do this for the apostrophe and the " symbols that are different put the symbol in the cell
  body.replaceText("\\Q’\\E","'");
  // works 
  body.replaceText("\\Q”\\E",'"') 
  // ???? replace all unsupported characters from sheet means in my cell 

  /** symbols to test which works >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ok for the McDonald*?()\.,;%#(){!s . how about the "  ***/
  body.replaceText( "\\Q" + text_before + "\\E" +  ".*?"  + "\\Q" + text_after + "\\E", text_before + text_between + text_after );
```